# set data inside row and column in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

[image]

i need to set data like this

i have tried taken row first then column then again row, but in row i am unable to set space between job id and 011.

```
Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                      width: 50.0,
                      height: 50.0,
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          image: new DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            image: AssetImage('assets/noimage.jpg'),
                          ))),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Job id',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                          Text('011',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                        ],
                      ),
],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

set space between job id and it's data but in my case it will `jobid011` .

Comment: If you use padding it will not be responsive, It is better to use Spacer() widget instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
   Row( 
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0),),
        Container(
          margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
          width: 50.0,
          height: 50.0,
          color: Colors.red
         ),
         Expanded(
          child:  Column(
          children: <Widget>[
             Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Job id',
                    style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                  Text('011',
                    style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                    fontSize: 16.0,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                 ],
                )
              ],
             ),
            ),
            Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),)

           ],
       ),
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spacer() Widget to make this work

```
    Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  new Container(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                      width: 50.0,
                      height: 50.0,
                      decoration: new BoxDecoration(
                          shape: BoxShape.circle,
                          image: new DecorationImage(
                            fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            image: AssetImage('assets/noimage.jpg'),
                          ))),
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                     mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Job id',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                           Spacer(),
                          Text('011',
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal)),
                        ],
                      ),
],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

see more about this [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Spacer-class.html)

Answer (score 0):

**You can use** `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start` for space between `Text Widget`

```
 Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          child: Text(heading,
              style: AppTheme.textStyleWith(15, Colors.black)
                  .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ),
        Expanded(
          child: Text(
            details,
            style: AppTheme.textStyleWith(15, Colors.black),
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
```